"Por que me da error False al imprimir el resultado?
Usuario= int(input("Cantidad de Divisas que posee: "))
OpcionesDivisas= int(input("Accion a realizar 1.Comprar Divisas 2.Vender Divisas:  "))
if OpcionesDivisas==1 :
int(input("Valor De Divisas a comprar: "))
Resultado1= OpcionesDivisas==1+Usuario
print(Resultado1)
elif OpcionesDivisas==2:
int(input("Valor De Divisas a Vender: "))
Resultado2= OpcionesDivisas==-Usuario 
print(Resultado2)

El codigo me da un error ( False ) al imprimir cualquier opcion y no entiendo por que pdta: soy nuevo en programación

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! tu codigo esta identado asi de esa forma? si no, por favor editalo e identalo como corresponde.. si esta asi, el problema es que justamente le falta toda la identacion...

Hola, a ver, te imprime un boleano porque ese es el resultado de OpcionesDivisas==1+Usuario,  estás usando el operador de comparación de igualdad (==), lo anterior se traduce en "¿Es OpcionesDivisa  igual a Usuario + 1" y el resultado es un bool (True/False), "Si" o "No"... lo mismo para Resultado2. Deberias explicar que resultado esperas, no se muy bien porqué estás usando el operador de igualdad aquí ni el porqué del  +1, OpcionDivisas es el tipo de operación... Si lo que quieres es sumar o restar sería simplemente algo como Resultado1 =  valor_del_input + Usuario.

Como decia mi amigo Jack, el destripador, vamos por partes.
Usuario = int( input( "Cantidad de Divisas que posee: " ))
 # en esta linea, asignas a "Usuario" un valor

OpcionesDivisas = int( input( "Accion a realizar 1.Comprar Divisas 2.Vender Divisas:  " ))
 # aquí le asignas a "OpcionesDivisas

if OpcionesDivisas == 1:
 # estableces el "if" con su condición

int( input( "Valor De Divisas a comprar: " ))
 # empiezan los problemas, lo que sea que ingrese el usuario 
 # se pierde, ya que no lo asignas a ninguna variable

Resultado1 = OpcionesDivisas == 1 + Usuario
 # como te indica "FJSevilla", al haber un "==", la expresión devuelve un booleano
 # que resulta de la comparación de "OpcionesDivisas" con "( 1 + Usuario )

print( Resultado1 )
 # inprimes el... booleano obtenido

El resto del código, repite el esquema.
Lo que deberías usar es:
divisasUsuario = int( input( "Cantidad de Divisas que posee: " ))
OpcionesDivisas = int( input( "Accion a realizar 1.Comprar Divisas 2.Vender Divisas:  " ))
if OpcionesDivisas == 1:
    cantidadComprada = int( input( "Valor De Divisas a comprar: " ))

     # sumamos a las divisas, la cantidad comprada
    resultado1 = cantidadComprada + divisasUsuario
    print( resultado1 )
elif OpcionesDivisas == 2:
    cantidadVendida = int( input( "Valor De Divisas a Vender: " ))

     # restamos de la divisas, la cantidad vendida
    resultado2 = divisasUsuario - cantidadVendida
    print( resultado2 )

PD: cambié algunos nombres de variables, para que el código sea más auto explicativo.

Pareciera que buscas algo asi:
Usuario = int(input("Cantidad de Divisas que posee: "))
OpcionesDivisas = int(input("Accion a realizar 1.Comprar Divisas 2.Vender Divisas:  "))
if OpcionesDivisas == 1:
    valor = int(input("Valor De Divisas a comprar: "))
    Resultado1 = valor * Usuario
    print(Resultado1)
elif OpcionesDivisas == 2:
    valor = int(input("Valor De Divisas a Vender: "))
    Resultado2 = valor * Usuario
    print(Resultado2)

El código que publicas no tiene sentido.
